# How to form a differential equation, given temperature and direction of heat flow

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I am given the following information:
$$T(x, y) = xy − x$$ 
where $T$ represents temperature.

Heat flows in the direction $−\nabla T$ (perpendicular to the isothermals).

How do I use this to make a differential equation in $x$ and $y$? I know that $\nabla T = ( y-1 , x )$, but I have no idea how I'm meant to use that here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might formulate a problem of heat conduction in two dimensions ($x$ and $y$) and use the given solution of $T(x,y)$ to work backwards and develop boundary conditions. A simple example of heat conduction would be:

$$ \nabla^{2}T = 0,$$ where $\nabla^{2}$ is the Laplacian operator. So,

$$ \nabla^{2}T = \frac{\partial ^{2} T}{\partial x^{2}} + \frac{\partial ^{2} T}{\partial y^{2}} =0.$$ The expression for $T(x,y)$ you're given satisfies this. You can create some boundary conditions (just plug in $0$ and $1$ to the given expression) on an arbitrarily proposed domain of $0 \le x,y \ge 1,$ as

$$ T(x=0,y)=0, $$
$$ T(x=1,y)=y-1, $$
$$ T(x,y=0)=-x, $$
$$ T(x,y=1)=0. $$ Therefore your equation of $T(x,y)=xy-x$ satisfies the PDE:

$$ \nabla^{2}T = 0,$$
with boundary conditions as given above.

Hope this helps. Is this what you're looking for?

Cheers,

Paul Safier